# Vector going out of bounds without giving error

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector`. I check its size which is 6 but when I try to access `vec[6]` to check whether it will give error, I get no error but some number instead. Should not it give an error?

edit: something like:

```
struct Element
{
    std::vector<double> face;
};

int main()
{
    Element elm;

    .... // insert 6 elements into elm.face

    std::cout << elm.face.size() << std::endl; // answer is 6
    std::cout << elm.face[6] << std::endl; // answer is some number
}
```

Comment: size 6, so last is `vec[5]` starts with 0

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea that `vector` would throw an error on an invalid index using `operator[]`.  The docs certainly say otherwise.

Comment: `Notice that the first element has a position of 0 (not 1).` -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/

Comment: @Bill: I think they understand that indexes start at zero and that 6 is out of range, but they're wondering why accessing something out of range does not yield an error.

Comment: @EdS. are there any reasons that there is no bounds checking implemented for op `[]`?

Comment: @icktoofay: All one needs to do is read the docs to see that it results in UB

Comment: @Koushik: Because it slows things down.  That's what `at()` is for

Comment: `If the container size is greater than n, the function never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.` -- same link posted in my earlier comment.

Comment: @EdS.: I know, and that's what my answer states. I'm not wondering, the person that asked the question is!

Comment: 11 upvotes for simply failing to consult the documentation. Why?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`std::vector` performs bounds checking when the [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function is used, but [it does not perform any checks with `operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

When out of bounds `operator[]` produces undefined results.

Comment: The behavior is undefined, so implementations are **allowed** to introduce bounds checks; the difference from `at` is that bounds checks are **required** for `at`.

Answer (score 13):

As stated in kgraney's answer, this is undefined behaviour. However, most c++ libraries have some facility to abort, or raise an exception in such cases. Usually controlled by setting or unsetting specific compiler macro's.

I have made an overview of the relevant documentation:

## gnu libstdc++

- [Debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html)  -- general info about libstdc++ debugging
- [_GLIBCXX_DEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html)
- [_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/concept_checking.html), with -fconcepts -- enable c++ concepts

## clang libcxx

- [_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL=1](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html#using-debug-mode)

## boost

- [BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html) -- disable asserts in the boost library.

## Microsoft

- [Checked Iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx)
- [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx) -- set iterator debug level
- [Security Features in the CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt)
- _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS : disable deprecation warnings
- [_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985974.aspx) -- less safe(according to microsoft), but more standard compliant:
- [_SECURE_SCL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896.aspx) -- old method of setting iterator debug level
- [_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/has-iterator-debugging) - deprecated macro

Note that gnu and clang disable the checks by default, while microsoft has them enabled by default. If you are unaware of this, your code may run significantly slower in debug mode on a microsoft system.

Comment: ...may run significantly slower *in debug mode* on a microsoft system.

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behavior. Undefined behavior does not necessarily mean you'll get an error: you *might*, but you might instead get some result that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score -3):

Data structures are indexed starting at 0, so if you are accessing vec[6] then this is going to be out of bounds.  You are likely not getting an error due to a memory issue; there could be something there from previous code you have run, or some similar error.  Please post code.